# jQuery dialog - how to use different styles for each dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

I use jQuery UI dialog for different dialogs on a website. Now I wondered if there was an easy way to use different styles for different dialogs?

E.g. alerts like "really delete..." should have a different style than other messages...

Now, there are classes used in the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Title of dialog">Text of dialog</div>
```

However, the actual style is applied to `.ui-widget-header`, <strike>which I cannot find anywhere in the source text, so I guess jQuery replaces this at some point, is this true?</strike>

EDIT: from docs.jquery.com:

```
Sample markup with jQuery UI CSS Framework classes

<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title">Dialog title</span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="dialog">
      <p>Dialog content goes here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
Note: This is a sample of markup generated by the dialog plugin, not markup you should use to create a dialog. The only markup needed for that is <div></div>.
```

What is the best way to be able to have different styles for different dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also directly from the jQuery site:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ dialogClass: "alert" });
```

It says

> The specified class name(s) will be added to the dialog, for additional theming.

Answer (score 0):

```
         <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Title of dialog" style="//put your styling here" >Text of dialog</div>
```

Inline styling like that over rides all css sheets

you can use different DIV's for the different dialogs,

```
          <div id="dialog-confirm0" title="Title of dialog" style=" put your styling here>Text of dialog</div> 
          <div id="dialog-confirm1" title="Title of dialog" style=" put your styling here>Text of dialog</div> 
          <div id="dialog-confirm2" title="Title of dialog" style=" put your styling here>Text of dialog</div>
```

use

```
                $( "#dialog-confirm0" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
         });
```

then you could use , in a different spot

```
                $( "#dialog-confirm1" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
         });
```

If you want to do it with css clases , then you can add a different class to the DIV using jQuery , and add !important to override the styling that comes from jQuery UI .

ex.

```
                background-color: #454545 !important;
                color: #000 !important;
```